# How to allow the internal network only to access NTP service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, iptables, firewall

I am having a firewall with the IP of 10.0.0.2 which has an NTP server. I want only the internal network 10.0.0.0/24 to access the NTP server. I don't want to allow any external networks to access the NTP server. Please note that I want to set these permissions on the firewall and I have to use iptables. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: It's port 123. But why do you need to use iptables? That is, why not just configure `ntpd` to listen only on the internal address?

Comment: Given your question history, I'd suggest two generic questions instead of the concrete ones posted: "How do I determine which ports a given server application listens on?" and "How can I configure iptables to drop all connections to a given port except those that arrive on a specific interface?" Those might even have answers here already

Comment: Checking the documentation for each specific server application is also pertinent, as many have options to listen only on a given address. The firewall rules may still be useful, but they are less necessary if the application isn't listening on the external interface to begin with

Answer (score 1):

## How do I configure a server application to bind only to a given interface?

This varies by application; check the documentation. In the specific example of `ntpd` you could use

```
# excerpt from ntp.conf
interface ignore wildcard
interface listen 127.0.0.1
interface listen 10.0.0.2
```

in your configuration file.  This should be the first choice, as you will likely be making changes to the default configurations of servers anyway, and it provides a bit of safety if the firewall is somehow bypassed (e.g. accidentally set to allow everything).

## How do I determine what port a server application uses?

Many if not all systems include `/etc/services`. For example, in Arch Linux this file is provided by the `iana-etc` package, which is a dependency of `filesystem` — the "base files" required for the system to operate.  You can search for your protocol:

```
$ awk ' $1 == "ntp" ' /etc/services
ntp        123/tcp
ntp        123/udp
```

This tells you that the NTP protocol uses port 123 in both TCP and UDP. You could also do, for example, SSH

```
$ awk ' $1 == "ssh" ' /etc/services
ssh        22/tcp
ssh        22/udp
ssh        22/sctp
```

to see that SSH is on port 22.  This isn't necessarily as reliable as checking the server's documentation, but it generally works.

## How can I have iptables drop traffic from a specific interface?

If this is your goal, you're doing it backward.  Drop everything by default, and allow the wanted traffic.

Here, you would have something like (oversimplified):

```
# modified excerpt from iptables.rules
# to be sourced by
#    iptables-restore < iptables.rules
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Allow inputs on non-privileged ports
-A INPUT -p tcp ! --dport 0:1023 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp ! --dport 0:1023 -j ACCEPT

# Allow anything on the loopback interface
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow NTP access from the LAN
# you could use
#    -i internal-interface-name
# instead of (or in addition to)
#    -s 10.0.0.0/24
# to filter by interface rather than source address
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP from anywhere
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH from the external interface
# replace external-interface-name with the actual name
-A INPUT -p tcp -i external-interface-name --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Maybe explicitly reject and log:
# -A INPUT -j LOG --log-level warning --log-prefix "Rejected input: "
# -A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
# -A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
# -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
COMMIT
```

The "Allow NTP access from the LAN" block is an example for the particular server and source-address-range you've specified. I've also included a couple other examples to build from.

In this configuration, you do have to be careful to explicitly allow access to services as you enable them.